# MVC & Elmah - Can Elmah be displayed using MVC site layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Lots of great information on Elmah and MVC 3/4 out there. I've been using Elmah in projects for a few years now.

One thing I haven't seen asked or addressed is displaying Elmah using an MVC site's layout.

Anyone ever try this?

I am developing a MVC-4 project and have Elmah currently running in it's own area. I used the setup at [Joel.net](http://joel.net/logging-errors-with-elmah-in-asp.net-mvc-3--part-1--setup)

It's working very nice as is, but would really like to hear from the community in regards to displaying the results in a site's layout.

Any tips/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great article over at: http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/

It's a pretty comprehensive article on combining Elmah, Health Monitoring, Log4Net, and NLog to cover all the logging you would ever possibly need in any MVC application. It covers the objects as well as the Entity objects, controllers, views, etc., and doing so into one UI for all of them.

The article is dated (2010) and in MVC 2. I was able to take Darren's approach, convert it to VB.NET and get it all running in a large MVC 4 application I am working on.

Even if you don't use it, it's a great tutorial and well worth the read.

Enjoy and mad props to Darren for that article.

Comment: Note that series starts with this post: http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/logging-on-mvc-part-1/

Answer (score 5):

No, at least not directly. Elmah uses an HttpHandler to display errors, which completely ignores the MVC pipeline.

You have a few options that require some extra work:

- Create your own views. You may need to reference the Elmah source as some of the required classes might be internal.
- Display Elmah in an iframe in your own view. It's probably not the best option, but it should work.
- Try [Elmah.MVC](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/elmah.mvc.controller), which looks like an MVC controller for Elmah:

> Painless integration of ELMAH functionality into ASP.NET MVC
>   Application. Creates Admin area and corresponding controller, so ELMAH
>   is availble by /admin/elmah route.

Comment: Already using Elmah.MVC, and while it does have an Elmah controller, each action method serves up a custom ElmahResult instead of an action result/view.

Comment: It is indeed working for me. Elmah is in an Area called "SiteAdmin", and it has its own controller (ElmahController). Again though, the controller is mainly implemented to keep the url structure within the MVC pipeline.

Comment: So does this answer your question?

Comment: No, the ElmahController does not return a view in any of it's action methods.

Comment: Have you tried it? The `ElmahResult` is there in place of Views.

Comment: Yes, I have it working as it is written (converted to VB). But again, each method returns an ElmahResult, not a view that you pass a model to.

Comment: The ElmahResult creates an instance of a subclass of a webforms Page with lots of HttpContext dependencies and private/internals that can't easily be accessed.  It doesn't even look like you could use a webforms masterpage with it.  I'm guessing less effort to rewrite it than find a way to mangle it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the SQL Server module for Elmah, you can save the errors to a SQL database. Once that is done, you could write a custom app or page to read from the DB and present in any manner which you would like.

Comment: Way too much work Nolan, and shouldn't be necessary when all the functionality of the UI is already in place.

Comment: Fair enough... however, after looking into the ELMAH MVC project more, it does look like a controller is included. I'm guessing the next step would be to take the model/data returned from the controller and manipulate it in a custom view, which should be straight forward. That being said, I now know that there is an ELMAH MVC project which I didn't know of before, so I might have to use it also (thanks jrummell for the link to Elmah.MVC)

Comment: Nolan, it is pretty well done and I am using it myself. I have already converted it over to VB.net, so if you need that version, just give me a shout.

Answer (score 0):

```
If ("site's layout" == in-line, on the page){
    edit the masterstylesheet to include elmah.
or 
    wire it into a jQuery plugin.
} else {
    have you considered Glimpse's role in the display chain?
}
```

Comment: I have not considered that yet, but Glimpse is indeed on the implementation menu.